# Salvar Grafico de uma planilha em uma pasta pelo VB

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Olá, pessoal. Sou iniciante em programação VB e estou com um projeto, onde acesso uma planilha e insiro dados nela e esses dados são mostrados em gráfico. Como faço para salvar esse gráfico como imagem em uma pasta e depois usar essa imagem? É possível?
Eu uso o VB e Excel 2010.

Comment: A planilha possui somente um gráfico fixo?

Comment: Bom dia Danieltajeshi, o planilha possui outros gráficos, eu preciso salvar esses gráficos e coloca-los em um relatório. O sistema possui conexão ADO com banco de dados Acsses.

Comment: Eu escrevi uma resposta em VBA, porque a Tag estava somente com Excel. Mas você está utilizando o VBA ou o VB.NET? Se for VB a minha resposta está errada. Favor editar as Tags do seu post corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

### Salvar Gráficos como PNG

Para salvar todos os gráficos utilize este código:

```
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        x = 1
        For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
            co.Chart.Export SeuDiretório & "\" & sht.Name _
                          & "_" & x & ".png", "PNG"
            x = x + 1
        Next co
    Next sht
```

### Código Completo

Um código mais completo para salvar todos os gráficos na mesma pasta do arquivo e caso não encontre o arquivo, abrir uma janela para escolher o caminho do diretório:

```
Sub ExportarGrafico()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim co As ChartObject
    Dim x As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
Inicio:
    If strPath <> "" Then
        For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            x = 1
            For Each co In sht.ChartObjects
                co.Chart.Export strPath & "\" & sht.Name _
                              & "_" & x & ".png", "PNG"
                x = x + 1
            Next co
        Next sht
    Else
        MsgBox "A pasta do arquivo não foi encontrada - Escolha a pasta."
        strPath = GetFolder
        GoTo Inicio
    End If
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select folder to export Charts to"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show = True Then sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

### Explicação

#### strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

É atribuída à variável de String `StrPath`  o diretório do arquivo de Excel.

#### If strPath <> "" Then

Se encontra o caminho do arquivo, ou seja, a variável strPath não é vazia, exporta todos os gráficos como PNG.

#### Else

Caso contrário:

```
    MsgBox "A pasta do arquivo não foi encontrada - Escolha a pasta."
```

Mostra a mensagem de que o arquivo não foi encontrado.

```
    strPath = GetFolder
```

Chama a função GetFolder para escolher uma pasta.

```
    GoTo Inicio
```

Volta ao `Inicio:`

Comment: Bom dia, Daniel. Agradeço pela atenção e peço desculpas pela falta de informações, como disse sou iniciante, estou utilizando o Visual Basic 6.0 e nem entendo ainda as diferenças. Eu criei um sistema de controle de cursos, onde os alunos são cadastrados e informações como se foi aprovado, reprovado ou desistente, ele também contém informações de cargo ou função. O sistema faz a contagem desses dados e insere na planilha. Até aqui tá tudo certo, o que falta é salvar esses gráficos como imagem, salvar o caminho deles no Banco de dados para coloca-los no relatório para impressão.