# Desenvolvimento de Automação em VBA - tratamento de Erro em Loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma automação em VBA que acessa determinado site e pega algumas informações do mesmo, porem eu estou tendo um problema nisso.

O site (Santander - Benner) é muito mal feito, muitas partes foram construídas de forma que aparenta emendar com o que já tinha feito, ou seja, apenas adicionaram mais recursos e não configuraram o projeto todo.

Indo direto ao ponto, eu queria saber **se tem alguma forma de trabalhar com o tratamento de erro GoTo em forma de loop**.

*Exemplo:* enquanto ocorrer erro, faça... ou, é erro, volte até "x" linha e faça o procedimento até chegar nesse verificador novamente, caso tenha erro novamente, refaça e por ai vai... Não sei se deixe bem claro, mas é fazer o GoTo em loop.

Comment: Olá, M. Marins. Formatei seu texto para melhor entendimento e contribuição dos participantes.

Comment: Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268706/75104). Em que O `If` é utilizado em conjunto com o `GoTo`. Se ocorrer tudo ok realiza as funções, caso contrário chama a função `GetFolder` e volta para `Inicio:`

Comment: @danieltakeshi obrigado pelo link, o exemplo do link me fez achar uma solução para este problema, utilizando algumas pesquisas e vendo o que você me mandou, deu para montar um solução

Comment: Seria bom você adicionar à pergunta o código que você tem para melhor entendimento.

Comment: @tony esta a baixo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de analisar [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268376/salvar-grafico-de-uma-planilha-em-uma-pasta-pelo-vb/268706#268706), e algumas outras pesquisas, achei uma solução.

```
continue:
     'seta variavel operacao
     Set operacao = ie.document.getElementById("tsk_toolbar")

     'continua caso tenha erro
     On Error Resume Next

     'recebe o valor caso tenha dito erro
     va = Err.Number

     'verifica se teve erro, valor diferente que zero
     'caso tenha, retorna e seta novamente 
     If va <> 0 Then
          GoTo continue
     Else
          'nao faca nada
     End If
```

Apenas explicando novamente o porque disso, e não apenas tratar o erro em si. O site que estou trabalhando é muito ruim para se fazer automação, e esse erro acontece porque a pagina demora muito para carregar, então não achando outro meio de resolver este problema, eu criei esta forma, que resolve meu problema.

Comment: Outra maneira é utilizar somente: `If va <> 0 Then GoTo continue`, sem o `Else`